# Backgrounds in menus Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, themes, gtk

I'm having this little problem in all themes I install - the background color of all the window menu items is light-gray instead of the dark I expected.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and using gnome-config-tool to configure them. I've installed all themes in the .themes folder in my home.

[image]

Using Cinnamon and Ubuntu 12.10

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you installing them with `sudo`? Maybe you'll have to open `gnome-config-tool` to change light-gray to dark.

Comment: I found out that the problem is with the GNOME version. Mine is 3.6 and the themes doesn't have compatibility with this version. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Add it as an answer. You'll be able to accept after two days `:)`